# CORS Issue: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Error

Tags: authentication, cors, backend

I'm working on a web application with a frontend running on port 3000 and a backend on port 4000. My application includes a login form, and when I try to log in, I encounter a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue. The error message in my browser's console is:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/app/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:4000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

- Firstly, I tried to use Rob--W's `cors-anywhere` GitHub library to bypass the CORS issue, but it didn't resolve the problem. (based on an old stackoverflow question I can't link because the algorithm will read it as spam :(

Secondly, I tried modifying the headers in my server.js file using the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
const routeUrls = require('./routes/routes')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("dotenv").config();
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

dotenv.config()
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () => console.log("MongoDB is connected."))
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is up and running!"))

app.use ((req, res, next) =>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4000");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    next();
    cors({
        origin: ["http://localhost:4000"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        credentials: true,
      })
})
  

    
  app.use(cookieParser());
  
  app.use(express.json());
  
  app.use("/app", routeUrls);
```

```
login.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const Login = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    

    const loginData = {
      email,
      password,
    };
    if(!email || !password) {
      toast.error("Please fill out all fields");
      return;
    }
    const emailFormatPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if (!emailFormatPattern.test(email)) {
      toast.error("Please enter a valid email address");
      return;
    }
    if (password.length < 7 || !/[0-9]/.test(password) || !/[!@#$%^&*]/.test(password)) {
      toast.error("Incorrect Password or Email");
      return;
    }
    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/app/login", loginData)
    .then((res) => {
      toast.success("Login successful");
      
      console.log(res.data);
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
      history("/dashboard");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
  
  

  return (
    <form
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        maxWidth: "300px",
        margin: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <TextField
        label="Email"
        type="email"
        variant="outlined"
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        variant="outlined"
        name="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Login
      </Button>
      <p>
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**My expected outcome:
**hat when I click the "Login" button on my login form, the login request should be successfully sent to the backend, and I should be redirected to the dashboard upon, as detailed in login.jsx I linked.